# How to switch datax in toolbar to Addax, or toolbar new tools

Tags: apache-dolphinscheduler

Because the greenplum synchronization in datax is too inefficient, you need to switch to another plugin for synchronization

Answer (score 1):

I found I could just upload addax to /opt/soft and change the name to datax

Answer (score 0):

This approach doesn't make any sense and sounds like a mere replacement of the icon.

2.0 uses the mechanism of Plugin, which you can implement by extending the plugin

Comment: This is not answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation, you could comment on other posts.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30035418)

Comment: Version 2.0 has not been released yet，Versions below 2.0 can only do this because the Datax plugin does not meet the requirements